# My usb ports outputs different voltages

Tags: voltage, usb

I have made circuit that runs on USB. however, when i plugged into front panel of my pc or raspberry pi, it only gets around 3.3v, but when i plugged it into back of my pc, it gets 5v as intended. Shouldn't all USB output same voltage? I have tried both USB 3.0 and 2.0, and on back of my pc, 3.0 outputs 5V and 2.0 outputs 2v. the other ports outputs same 3v whichever 3.0 or 2.0
Edit: Rebooting solved the problem :(

Comment: What is your circuit and how much current it takes?

Comment: Check the voltage on your USB ports with NO LOAD.    i.e. no raspberry pi connected.   Are they 5V now?   I'm sure they are.  The USB standard is 5V.   Nothing else should ever be found in a USB port.   If you overload a USB port, it'll respond with lowered voltage.  It's got built-in current limiting.   Not every USB port is the same, some can output much higher current than others.

Comment: ^^^^   Unless, of course, you're connecting something completely wrong    ;)

Comment: Raspberry pi is powered from wall charger, so raspberry pi isn't loading from my pc.
I have shorted USB port in front panel before by accident, and I got an alert from window saying USB port is overloaded, and it cut power. I'm not sure if it fried my USB port little bit then.
I personally don't want to desolder usb cable from circuit, since I'm not good at soldering.
My circuit takes 5v from usb port and use step-up voltage module to make it 7.2v. and then power 10 IR led in series

Comment: You still did not say how much the load is. How many amps you are pulling from USB 5V with the boost module? Or how much current goes into IR LEDs?

Comment: @Justme IR LEDs uses 83mA and voltage is 7.4 on backpanel. Funny thing is, I tested again and i got correct voltage :( Rebooting solved the problem. Sorry to bother you

Comment: I suspect that the boost converter input capacitance is out of the limits for USB hot plugging and the USB ports protection circuitry triggers to protect is. USB ports are not designed to be power supplies for arbitrary experiments.